# Coxeter numbers for semisimple and reductive algebraic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, root-systems

I'd like to know how to define the coxeter number for semisimple and reductive algebraic groups.  I know that for a simple algebraic group $G$, we can fix a maximal torus $T\subset G$, which acts on $\mathfrak{g}=\mathrm{Lie}(G)$ by the adjoint action.  Then $\mathfrak{g}$ decomposes into a direct sum of eigenspaces with eigenvalues given by roots in the character group $X(T)$.  These roots form an irreducible abstract root system inside of $\mathbb{R}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}X(T)$.  Choosing a base of the root system $\Phi$ leads to a unique highest root, and the coxeter number of $G$ can be defined as

$$h(G)=1+\sum a_i$$

where the $a_i$ are the coefficients of the simple roots in the linear combination expressing the highest root.

Now, if I have a semisimple or reductive group, then the root system of $G$ is not necessarily irreducible, so I'm not sure there is a unique highest root with respect to some chosen base.  However, in the literature I still see reference to the coxeter number of a reductive group.  How is this defined?  Thanks!